# What kind of router/switch do I need?

Tags: networking

I have following devices I want to network.

1> Modem (Regular dsl modem)

2> A gateway for internal LAN (Corp datacenter)

3> A standalone server

I want to connect 1 -> 2 and 1-> 3

And I have multiple static IPs. I want one IP for #3 and a few for #2.

So what do I need between 1, 2 and 3? A router? Or some type of switch will do? Or do I need another type of modem?

Sorry for asking such a dumb question but I am developer and doing sys admin task here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a situation like this I would buy a small corporate firewall like a Netscreen SSG5.  I would then configure it so that the firewall had a 'DMZ' security zone, and put the server into the DMZ.  Then I would configure a MIP (mapped IP) from the 'untrust' (internet) zone to the DMZ zone.  The firewall would then pass traffic from the MIP through to the server.  You can pass all traffic through, or you can set up policies to only pass particular traffic through (ie only http and/or ssh, or whatever).  This can be repeated for each IP you want to map back to the server.

This can be done with just about any "corporate" strength firewall, for example cisco, the terms (MIPs) would be different but the theory is the same.

If you want a basic basic firewall (like a Linksys or something) and want to hang the server directly on the internet, you will probably need a second set of PPPoE credentials for the server.  In that case, you can get away with a cheap switch in between the firewall, DSL modem, and server.  However you need to keep a much closer eye on the server to ensure that vulnerabilities don't accumulate.

The former solution is more expensive but potentially more secure; and you will end up with a better quality firewall than a $60 Linksys.

Answer (score 1):

OpenBSD and PF.  it'll do everything you want and you get to learn new stuff as you implement your solution.  The gateway setup guide in the pf users manual is just awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to go the [DD-WRT Route](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php) and pay $60 for a linksys and then put your own custom firmware on there.  We did this for a year or so before switching over to something like a checkpoint @home product.  I think for what you want the DD-WRT custom firmware is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

A box with [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) installed will do what you want. You can configure it to either route or or do 1-to-1 NAT mappings between public/private IPs.

Do report back what you try.